# Cmake error libwww when compiling Ryzom

Tags: c++, cmake-gui, ryzom

I get these errors when I try to configure in cmake:

> Could NOT find Libwww (missing: LIBWWW_LIBRARIES LIBWWW_INCLUDE_DIR)

but I couldn't find any answer in google, I tried to download "w3-libwww" but I don't know how to include it on project.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://ryzomcore.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RC/Build+Source+on+Windows

I downloaded and installed all SDK and pre-requisites and I try to generate for Visual Studio C++ 10 (2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use either develop or compatibility-develop branch, the default branch has not been updated for a while and we removed dependency on libwww since :)

Comment: oh! thank you so much!
I changed in tortoise with cmd: hg pull && hg update develop - and it worked as well